# calculating daily winnings with django

Tags: django, orm, aggregate-functions

I have a model class which represents a user bet. I would like to calculate daily winnings for the whole database (not a single user). Winnings for each user bet is calculated with the formula `odds * coins` (when result=1).

```
class UserBet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bet = models.ForeignKey(Bet)
    coins = models.FloatField(default=0.0) 
    placed = models.DateTimeField(editable=False) #when user places the bet
    result = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0) # 1: win, 0: no result yet, -1: lose
    odds = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    week_number = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    year = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    modified = models.DateTimeField() #when result is updated
```

I get daily coins placed for successful results like this (MySql):

`UserBet.objects.filter(result=1).extra({'date_modified':"date(modified)"}).values('date_modified').annotate(coins_sum=Sum('coins'))`

however this not what I want. Coins placed by each user should get multiplied with each user-bet odds in order to get the daily winnings.

Is this possible, at all?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `QuerySet.extra` method:

```
UserBet.objects.filter(result = 1).extra({'winnings':'odds * coins'})...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and I don't get daily aggregated results, anymore. This is not a big problem. I can do some post processing and reach the result I want. I am pasting some part of what I got: `[{'winnings': 62.5, 'coins_sum': 25.0, 'date_modified': datetime.date(2012, 4, 27)}, {'winnings': 162.0, 'coins_sum': 54.0, 'date_modified': datetime.date(2012, 4, 28)}, {'winnings': 25.5, 'coins_sum': 15.0, 'date_modified': datetime.date(2012, 4, 27)},...`